# FileOutputStream.writeBytes out of bounds

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

My Program reads a file into a byte array and then tries to carve out a bmp image from the file. The problem is I am getting an out of bounds error.

```
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
{
    FileInputStream fileInputStream=null;

    File file = new File("C:/thumbcache_32.db");

    byte[] bFile = new byte[(int) file.length()];

    System.out.println("Byte array size: " + file.length());

    try {
        //convert file into array of bytes
    fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    fileInputStream.read(bFile);

    fileInputStream.close();


    //convert array of bytes into file
    FileOutputStream fileOuputStream = 
              new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/zak/Desktop/thumb final/Carved_image.bmp"); 
    fileOuputStream.write(bFile,1573278,1577427);
    fileOuputStream.close();

    System.out.println("Done");
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

The size of the byte array one the file is loaded into is "3145728"

and I am trying to copy bytes "1573278" to "1577427". As you can see these bytes are within bounds of the byte array so im unsure why  I am getting this error

**output of program  when run**

```
Byte array size: 3145728
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
at Byte_copy.main(Byte_copy.java:28)
```

Comment: It's `write(data[], offset, len)` (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#write(byte[],%20int,%20int)) not `(data[], from, to)`

Comment: Thank you for your help my code is working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FileOutputStream.write](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#write(byte[],%20int,%20int)) takes 3 params, the last 2 being the offset and length. So pretend we have an array of size 10:

```
byte [] arr = new byte[10];
FileOutputStream out = ...
out.write(arr, 5, 5); // writes the last 5 bytes of the file, skipping the first 5
out.write(arr, 0, 10); // writes all the bytes of the array
out.write(arr, 5, 10); // ERROR! index out of bounds, 
                       // your attempting to write 10 bytes starting at offset 5
```

Now in your code you use `fileOuputStream.write(bFile,1573278,1577427);`

and `1573278+1577427=3150705`, as you can see 3150705 > 3145728. So your getting an index out of bounds because either your offset or your limit is to high. I dont know the meaning behind why you chose those 2 numbers but you could do something like this.

```
 fileOuputStream.write(bFile, 1573278, bFile.length - 1573278);
```

Comment: Are I see I completly miss understood how the it worked thank you for clearing it up for me my code works perfectly now thank you very much